# How to deal with R/exams nops_pdf string questions?

Tags: r, r-exams

I created several nops_pdf exams which produced several `.rds` with the exam information. I usually do it, and then use this code (provided by Achim) to merge all `.rds`:

```r
## readRDS all *.rds files in the current working directory
x <- lapply(Sys.glob("exam/*.rds"), readRDS)

## combine all resulting lists
y <- do.call("c", x)

## saveRDS into a single .rds file
saveRDS(y, "exam/all.rds")
```

However, I created my nops exams with two string questions each. Everything seems to work correctly when I merge the different `.rds` in one single file. After running the `nops_eval()` function and checking the results I noticed that the string questions were not being accurately evaluated. I had to correct each one individually, each with its corresponding `rds` file and scans. Any idea why it does not work as usual?

Comment: Are the `string` questions always in the same position (e.g., always the last two) in all of the separate `.rds` files? That would be the only thing I see in the code. Otherwise it would be good to have a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: No, they are in random positions. Any idea of how it might be possible to add them without creating this type of "conflict."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment `nops_eval()` expects that the same exercise across replications has the same type and is associated with the same number of points. So, for example, all first exercises must be schoice and worth 2 points, all the second exercises mchoice and worth 3 points, and all third exercises string and worth 5 points.

When you use a single `exams2nops()` call, the code tries to check for this (at least to a certain degree). If you manually combine output from several `exams2nops()` calls you might circumvent this though and end up with the string exercises in different (random) positions. This will then lead to incorrect evaluations.

Let's assume that you have three schoice questions, five mchoice questions, and two string questions. And you want the schoice questions and mchoice questions in random order, then you could do it like this:

```
exm <- list(
  c("sc1.Rmd", "sc2.Rmd", "sc3.Rmd"),
  c("mc1.Rmd", "mc2.Rmd", "mc3.Rmd", "mc4.Rmd", "mc5.Rmd"),
  "str1.Rmd",
  "str2.Rmd"
)
exams2nops(exm, nsamp = c(3, 5, 1, 1), ...)
```

As a concrete example you can use:

```
exm <- list(
  c("deriv2.Rmd", "tstat2.Rmd", "swisscapital.Rmd"),
  c("switzerland.Rmd", "capitals.Rmd", "boxplots.Rmd", "ttest.Rmd", "anova.Rmd"),
  "function.Rmd",
  "countrycodes.Rmd"
)
```

Then the schoice questions will appear in random order but always as exercises 1-3, the mchoice questions will be in random order in exercises 4-8, the function exercise will always be question 9, and the country codes exercise always question 10.

Comment: Okay, so when inserting some item with different points or different types of questions (i.e., sc, mc, string...) I must keep them in the same order.